# Table(s) design for Stock Holding Adjustment table, 2 tables or 1?

Tags: sql, database-design

I currently have an inventory type table (just showing the fields that matter):

```
Timestamp Account User  Symbol Locates 
---------+-------+---- +------+--------
 2012-...| ABC   | Joe | ZZZ  | 1000
---------+-------+---- +------+--------
```

Whenever users need to adjust the number of locates (shares), they post a new record to the table.  I need to store almost the exact same data for user to adjust their number of held shares. In fact, the only field which would be different is the `Locates` field, which would be called `Shares` for an adjustment to shares, e.g.:

```
Timestamp Account User  Symbol  Shares
---------+-------+---- +------+--------
 2012-...| ABC   | Joe | ZZZ  | 2000
---------+-------+---- +------+--------
```

The question is whether it is better to have 2 tables one for the locates, and one for the shares, or whether it is better to have 1 table, rename the `Locates` column to `Shares` and add an Enum type column to indicate the transaction type ('LOCATES','POSITION').

There is no reporting aspect to this as of yet.  It is just used by an application store changes made by users, and to rebuild the locates and shares on restarting the application.  I can't see a strong advantage to either approach, so this is more of a "what is the best practice" type of question.

**UPDATE**

After reading some comments, I realize it is hard to answer without knowing how this table is used. Here is hopefully a short explanation:

At the end of each day, we wipe out trading data from the database, so that the next day it starts out empty of data. None of this locate/shares data is carried over from day to day.

Each morning the application starts up, and loads owned shares and located shares from flat data files which are published to the server daily by a third party (there is no data loaded from the database at the beginning of the day).  During the trading day, users can adjust the quantity of shares and/or locates by sending a message to the server.  This message updates the value in memory on the server, and also writes a record to this table to show what the correct *starting* value should be.  (Essentially overriding what was read in from the flat files).

If we need to restart the server during the day (a rare, but possible occurrence), on restart, data from the flat files is re-read back into the application.  Application also reads any records in this table,  and uses the most recent record for an account/symbol combination to override the value read from the flat data file. So this table functions as an additional daily data source if we have to restart the application.

Comment: At work our financial database uses the 2nd approach in a more consistent manner.

Comment: @EplusL: could you please explain what you mean by "more consistent"?  You mean because it enforces same data structure for all kinds of transactions?

Comment: It sounds like `Shares` is _derived_ information (Based off the running total of `Locates`), which you're generally not supposed to do (due to potential mismatches).  How many rows are we talking here?  You may be able to derive `Shares` dynamically.

Comment: @X-Zero: `Shares` is not derived information. Each record is completely independent of the others.  However, only the most recent record for each account,symbol combination matters. `Locates` are shares you can *borrow* and `Shares` are shares you *own*. So they are separate properties of the same object. Shares and Locates are edited independently. User will adjust either quantity whenever something happens happen during the day that changes the base quantity.

Comment: @SamGoldberg short answer yes. We have tens of thousands of data columns spread over hundreds of tables. And table multiplication tends to involve complicated join operations for the more complex queries. So we'd rather add a column and double the rows in one table. Makes for simpler queries

Comment: But could you elaborate and be precise in the behavior of your locates and shares columns in relation to user input? I'm not clear what changes what to what and when. A data model will be easier to suggest once we have a clear idea of what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @EplusL: edited my question to give more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a third option, which is to have two data columns, one for locates and one for shares.

I don't think it is a good idea to have one generic column, whose value depends on an enumerated type.  Such a situation makes it too easy for an error to occur.  What is the total share adjustments on a given day?  Oops, I also included "locates".

Some databases support calculated/computed columns.  With such a database, you can also specify whether a row is for locates or shares (or both) with indicator columns:

```
IsLocate as (case when locates is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end),
IsAdjustment as (case when shares is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end),
```